# How can i replace UUIDGenerator in hibernate version 6.x?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, object, uuid

I have the following function that generate an optional ID. My problem is that UUIDgenerator was deprecated since hibernate 6.0 and i dont know how can i replace that. I am using Spring Boot 3.1.4 with Java 21.

```
package policy.generator;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class OptionalIdGenerator extends UUIDGenerator {
@Override
public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, obj).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(obj, session);
return id != null ? id : super.generate(session, obj);
}
}
```

I tried with this function:

```
package policy.generator;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;

public class OptionalIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        // Get current entity identifier using JPA API
        Object idObject = session.getPersistenceContext().getEntry(obj).getId();

        // Convert the identifier to Serializable if necessary
        Serializable id = (idObject instanceof Serializable) ? (Serializable) idObject : null;

        if (id != null) {
            return id;
        } else {
            return UUID.randomUUID();
        }
    }
}
```

But i received the following error:

```
Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityEntry.getId()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.engine.spi.PersistenceContext.getEntry(Object)" is null
```

Comment: Yeah, `org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator` is deprecated and you can use `org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator`

Comment: When you want to use your own solution, think what should happen in case `session.getPersistenceContext().getEntry(obj)` returns `null`? Extract that call into a local variable and handle it accordingly.

Comment: @kcsurapaneni ok i will search UuidGenerator docs, i need the same result

Comment: @cyberbrain exactly, returns null. I will try to adapt my variable return